# powershell runspace: An exception in a ScriptBlock doesn't identify the file and line number it occurred in , but the EndInvoke() call

Tags: powershell, runspace

The module I run in the script block has over 6000 lines of code. when it Throws an exception  I need to know the file and line number it occurred in.

But I do not.  Any expectation inside the script block always give me the same file and line number. The line I called EndInvoke().

Not very useful

Comment: Have you inspected the InnerExceptions on the Exception? After the exception is encountered try `$Error[0].Exception.InnerException`

Comment: I think you already got a really nice answer to one of your previous questions which is pretty similar to this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67745820/runspace-endinvoke-fails-to-return-all-the-scriptblocks-output-only-the-las).

Comment: Ok ,  this doesn't have the  line number and the script name  , but ErrorRecord seems to have this data.   Thanks , this should work.